# OpenVPN - pass only certain ports throught vpn

Tags: windows, networking, iptables, openvpn

I have OpenVPN server on VPS, I'm working on windows 8.1 and I want pass only certain ports throught VPN (eg. 3000, 3001).
Is it possible from windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenVPN has [two modes](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/311-what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-bridging-and-routing-in-terms-of-configuration):

- **TAP** (*Network Tapping System*) that simulates a *link layer* (OSI **layer 2**) device. In this mode both ends can be on the same subnet (e.g. `10.0.0.0/24`) and information are carried by ethernet **frames**, creating *network bridge*.
- **TUN** (*network TUNnel*) that simulates *internet layer* (OSI *network layer*, **layer 3**) device and carries IP **packets**.

Both modes allows you to either use the VPN for all traffic (default route to `0.0.0.0/0` on the remote side) or just the traffic within the same subnet (TAP) or to all or some subnets on the other end (TUN).

TCP and UDP (where you have the port numbers) works on the *transport layer* (/OSI **layer 4**). Therefore it is not a feature neither OpenVPN nor Windows can have but a **protocol level limitation** on all VPN implementations: It is **not possible with (Open)VPN**, but it'll be possible to configure at firewall.

**You can:**

- If you don't route all traffic through the VPN, you can use **different interfaces for different ports**, e.g. public http://example.com:80 vs. private `172.16.0.30:3001` for your Nessus client([?](http://search.cpan.org/~jwied/Net-Nessus-0.08/lib/Net/Nessus/Client.pm))
- Use [**SSH tunneling**](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/) instead of VPN, `ssh -L 3001:localhost:3001 user@example.com` (Local Port Forwarding)  or [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) (Connection > SSH > Tunnels: *Source port* `3001` & *Destination* `localhost:3001`, *Local*, *Auto*). This will bind the service to a port on your local machine i.e. you can connect to `localhost:3001`. (It is also possible to use different *source port* on local side.)

Comment: If it can't be done with openvpn on windows then it's a windows limitation. It's perfectly possible on a Linux client.

Comment: Pics or didn't happen. How can you do L4 things with L2/L3 virtual device? With `iptables` Mangle Tables you could decide different routes to the same IP based on port, but that a) wasn't the question (destination IP is different outside VPN) and b) it's not a feature of OpenVPN client but of a packet filter working on L2-L4.

Comment: Thanks for bringing awareness of SSH tunneling over PUTTY, I didn't know about it, and it's exactly what I needed.